# Windows UDP loss when source port changing

Tags: windows, udp, loss

I'm trying to implement an UDP server on windows, and use a simulator to do performance testing. And I found that if the source port is changing, packages will be lost about 50% when 5000pps, but if the source port is stable, packages will not be lost any. I try this on both Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008, they're the same. But on Linux it runs very well. Can anybody tell me why? Is there some limitation or configuration of UDP of Windows Server？

Comment: P.S.: the UDP server just do one thing: receive package and count, no other logic...

Comment: And I found that one CPU is very busy